# DynamoDB Query Date Field returning non date rows in Filter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

My DynamoDB table setup has the a Hash Key (PK) and a SortKey (SK1). I currently store a user ID and various sort keys relating to user information. For example,

| PK | SK1 |
| --- | --- |
| User#1 | DeviceToken#1234 |
| User#1 | CourseEnrolledDate#2022-01-20 |
| User#1 | CourseEnrolledDate#2022-01-19 |

I now need to know which courses a user has enrolled in after 2022-01-19, so I issue a query with PK=User#1 and KeyCondition= SK1 > CourseEnrolledDate#2022-01-19.

The result filters the CourseEnrolled correctly except that it also includes the DeviceToken#1234 item which should not be the case since the DeviceToken item does not have a date field to filter from. What am I doing wrong and how do you suggest I model my use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of the `>` operator, apply the `BETWEEN` operator  to `SK1` in the query's [key condition expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.KeyConditionExpressions):

```sql
AND SK1 BETWEEN CourseEnrolledDate#2022-01-20 AND CourseEnrolledDate#9
```

Where `a BETWEEN b AND c` returns true if `a` is greater than or equal to `b`, and less than or equal to `c`.

Comment: This almost works but the issue is that it gives the >= effect as opposed to >. What could I do to get the > effect? Also, what is the reasoning behind using #9 in the key condition.

Comment: @SalmanHasratKhan  `CourseEnrolledDate#2022-01-20` gets you the desired `>=` effect (answer edited).  DynamoDB is applying a string comparison of `a` and `b`.  The `#9` ensures your query is valid until `8999-01-01`.  Use `#9999` to make sure it runs for an additional millenium ;)

Comment: Interesting and a smart approach to solve the problem. Although in the future I am thinking of remodeling the user partition. I realized that even though I am storing the device tokens and the courses enrolled in the same user partition, I will never query the partition to return the device tokens and courses in one shot. A better approach for me would be separate the token and the courses partition. In this case I will be able to apply the > operator. Thanks for the smart solution to the problem in all cases :)